# Create my own entity generator on symfony using doctrine generator

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, generator

I am building an entity generator in order to update my DB's structure and data according to a distant one (DB), via SOAP WS...

I get the structure from an array, and am currently writing my entity classes by myself, with a file_put_content().

But as I advance, I can't help noticing that the Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator already does what I intend to do, way better I would ever be able to!!

So i was wondering if there was a way to use this implemented generator from my controller?
I mean, this is what Symfony is all about right? Using existing classes & bundles from anywhere in my code? :)

Any idea someOne?

Thx :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\BundleInterface;
use Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Generator\DoctrineEntityGenerator;
use Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\Validators;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    private $generator;

    public function generateEntityAction()
    {
        $format = "annotation"; //it can also be yml/php/xml
        $fields = "title:string(255) body:text";
        $withRepository = false; //true/false

        $entity = Validators::validateEntityName("MyBundle:EntityName");
        list($bundle, $entity) = $this->parseShortcutNotation($entity);
        $format = Validators::validateFormat($format);
        $fields = $this->parseFields($fields);
        $bundle = $this->get('service_container')->get('kernel')->getBundle($bundle);
        $generator = $this->getGenerator();
        $generator->generate($bundle, $entity, $format, array_values($fields), $withRepository);
    }

    protected function createGenerator()
    {
        return new DoctrineEntityGenerator($this->get('service_container')->get('filesystem'), $this->get('service_container')->get('doctrine'));
    }

    protected function getSkeletonDirs(BundleInterface $bundle = null)
    {
         $skeletonDirs = array();

         if (isset($bundle) && is_dir($dir = $bundle->getPath() . '/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton')) {
         $skeletonDirs[] = $dir;
         }

         if (is_dir($dir = $this->get('service_container')->get('kernel')->getRootdir() . '/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton')) {
         $skeletonDirs[] = $dir;
         }

         $skeletonDirs[] = __DIR__ . '/../Resources/skeleton';
         $skeletonDirs[] = __DIR__ . '/../Resources';

         return $skeletonDirs;
     }

     protected function getGenerator(BundleInterface $bundle = null)
     {
         if (null === $this->generator) {
              $this->generator = $this->createGenerator();
              $this->generator->setSkeletonDirs($this->getSkeletonDirs($bundle));
         }

         return $this->generator;
     }

     protected function parseShortcutNotation($shortcut)
     {
         $entity = str_replace('/', '\\', $shortcut);

         if (false === $pos = strpos($entity, ':')) {
             throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The entity name must contain a : ("%s" given, expecting something like AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post)', $entity));
         }

         return array(substr($entity, 0, $pos), substr($entity, $pos + 1));
     }

     private function parseFields($input)
     {
         if (is_array($input)) {
             return $input;
         }

         $fields = array();
         foreach (explode(' ', $input) as $value) {
             $elements = explode(':', $value);
             $name = $elements[0];
             if (strlen($name)) {
                 $type = isset($elements[1]) ? $elements[1] : 'string';
                 preg_match_all('/(.*)\((.*)\)/', $type, $matches);
                 $type = isset($matches[1][0]) ? $matches[1][0] : $type;
                 $length = isset($matches[2][0]) ? $matches[2][0] : null;

                 $fields[$name] = array('fieldName' => $name, 'type' => $type, 'length' => $length);
             }
         }

         return $fields;
     }
}
```

Mostly, it comes from Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand and Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GeneratorCommand

Comment: don't forget the write permission grants for MyBundle/Entity and MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine if you're using yml configuration

Comment: MMMmmm Yummy! This sounds very nice, clean and clever. Gonna work on it. I did it another way You can see in my own answer below. Thx!

Comment: Ok can't answer myself so here's what I did:
After writing the content manually and a file_put_content(), I call the `doctrine:generate:entities`command, then the `doctrine:schema:update`:

Comment: `$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);
// Generate getters & setters command
$options = array('command' => 'doctrine:generate:entities','name' => 'CompSoapBundle');
$application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
//Create Schema
$options2 = array('command' => 'doctrine:schema:update',"--force" => true);
$application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options2));
  `

Comment: Works very well for me. Thx! I was wondering: Do you know if there is a way to define the table name as well? (/**@ORM(name="table_name") ?

Comment: erf. sends me an error if I do it twice: `Entity "MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity" already exists.` :/ And I have to do it several times: whenever the distant base is updated..